# Where is C++ node implementation code?

Tags: roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I want to initialize a C# node.

And I want to consult the implementation of C++ node, I found several files in /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/src/libros may be useful.But I am not sure if these files are the right ones I am looking for.

Thanks~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12097/where-is-c++-node-implementation-code?/) by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1371 on 2011-11-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're really talking about [Implementing a Client Library](http://ros.org/wiki/Implementing%20Client%20Libraries) for C#. That page has a number of links to various documentation on the design of client libraries.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2011-12-01**:
Thanks~And now I am sure /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/src/libros contains the source codes I want to consult.